# Line Graph using D3 is not starting from the date i want it to

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

Below is my line graph where I am using 2 lines to show different values,

One line is blue and the other is red.

however the red line i want to start from 'Dec 27'(half way of the graph) instead of the start of the graph. I have been looking ways to do this but honestly I'm not sure how I can.

if someone is able to show me how i would appreciate that a lot.

Thanks you in advance!

This is my css:

```
path.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #004ecc;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

path.line2 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #cc0000;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

path.area {
  fill: #e7e7e7;
}

.guideline {
  margin-right: 100px;
  float: right;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.y.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.grid .tick {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 0.2px;
  opacity: 5;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.graph-column {
  float: left;
}

.tablebad thead tr {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.tablegood thead tr th {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

This is my d3.js:

```
   <script>

var margin = {
    top: 0,
    right: 90,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  padding = 1;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([10, width - 15]);

var x2 = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([10, width], .10)

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 100]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b %d"))
  .ticks(4)
  .tickPadding(2);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.XMAS);
  });

var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.JANSALES);
  });

//florida

var chart1 = d3.select("#LineChart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//needed for the grid
function make_y_axis() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
}

data1 = [{
    "date": "24-Dec-12",
    "XMAS": 2,
    "JANSALES": 0
  }, {
    "date": "25-Dec-12",
    "XMAS": 3,
    "JANSALES": 0
  },

  {
    "date": "26-Dec-12",
    "XMAS": 1,
    "JANSALES": 0
  },

  {
    "date": "27-Dec-12",
    "XMAS": 2.0,
    "JANSALES": 0
  },

  {
    "date": "28-Dec-12",
    "XMAS": 4.0,
    "JANSALES": 0
  },

  {
    "date": "29-Dec-12",
    "XMAS": 4.0,
    "JANSALES": 0
  }
  ,

  {
    "date": "29-Dec-12",
    "XMAS": 5,
    "JANSALES": 0
  },

  {
    "date": "30-Dec-12",
    "JANSALES": 3.0
  },

  {
    "date": "31-Dec-12",

    "JANSALES": 2.0
  },

  {
    "date": "01-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 3.0
  },

  {
    "date": "02-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 1.0
  },

  {
    "date": "03-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 3.0
  },

  {
    "date": "04-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 2.0
  },

  {
    "date": "05-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 2.0
  },

  {
    "date": "06-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 1.0
  },

  {
    "date": "07-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 2.0
  },

  {
    "date": "08-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 2.0
  },

  {
    "date": "09-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 3.0
  },

  {
    "date": "10-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 2.0
  },

  {
    "date": "11-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 3.0
  },

  {
    "date": "12-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 3.0
  },

  {
    "date": "13-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 2.0
  },

  {
    "date": "14-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 1.0
  }
];


var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#004ecc", "#cc0000"]);
//d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
data1.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.XMAS = +d.XMAS;
  d.JANSALES = +d.JANSALES;
});

// Scale the range of the data


x.domain(d3.extent(data1, function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));
y.domain([0, 10]);

x2.domain(data1.map(function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));

//add the grid
chart1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(make_y_axis()
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat("")
  )

chart1.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("d", valueline(data1));

chart1.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line2")
  .attr("d", valueline2(data1.filter(function(d) {
    return d.date > parseDate("29-Dec-12");
  })));

// Add the X Axis
chart1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
chart1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

chart1.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + 3) + "," + y(data1[0].JANSALES) + ")")
  .attr("x", ".1em")
  .attr("y", "-40")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .style("fill", "red")
  .style("font-size", "15")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .text("JAN SALES");

chart1.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + 3) + "," + y(data1[0].XMAS) + ")")
  .attr("x", ".1em")
  .attr("y", "10")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .style("font-size", "15")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .text("XMAS");

//plus 1: animation

var curtain = chart1.append('rect')
  .attr('x', -1 * width)
  .attr('y', -1 * height - 2)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('class', 'curtain')
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(180)')
  .style('fill', '#ffffff')

/* Optionally add a guideline */
var guideline = chart1.append('line')
  .attr('stroke', '#333')
  .attr('stroke-width', 0.4)
  .attr('class', 'guide')
  .attr('x1', 1)
  .attr('y1', 1)
  .attr('x2', 1)
  .attr('y2', height)

var t = chart1.transition()
  .delay(120)
  .duration(500)
  .ease('linear')
  .each('end', function() {
    d3.select('line.guide')
      .transition()
      .style('opacity', 0)
      .remove()
  });

t.select('rect.curtain')
  .attr('width', 0);
t.select('line.guide')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ', 0)')

d3.select("#show_guideline").on("change", function(e) {


});
</script>
```

And finally this is my Div tag where i am calling out the d3.js:

```
    <div id="florida"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the blue line and the red line use the same data set.

If you want the red line using a different data set, you can filter out the unwanted objects:

```
.attr("d", valueline2(data1.filter(function(d) {
    return d.date > parseDate("26-Dec-12");
})));
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 100,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 280 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  padding = 1;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([10, width - 15]);

var x2 = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, width], .25)

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b %d"))
  .ticks(4)
  .tickPadding(2);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.trump);
  });

var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.clinton);
  });

//florida

var chart1 = d3.select("#florida")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//needed for the grid
function make_y_axis() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
}

data1 = [{
    "date": "24-Dec-12",
    "trump": 2.0,
    "clinton": 0
  }, {
    "date": "25-Dec-12",
    "trump": 3.0,
    "clinton": 0
  },

  {
    "date": "26-Dec-12",
    "trump": 1.0,
    "clinton": 2
  },

  {
    "date": "27-Dec-12",
    "trump": 2.0,
    "clinton": 0
  },

  {
    "date": "28-Dec-12",
    "trump": 4.0,
    "clinton": 0
  }

  ,

  {
    "date": "29-Dec-12",
    "trump": 1.0,
    "clinton": null
  }
];


var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#004ecc", "#cc0000"]);
//d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
data1.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.trump = +d.trump;
  d.clinton = +d.clinton;
});

// Scale the range of the data


x.domain(d3.extent(data1, function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));
y.domain([0, 5]);

x2.domain(data1.map(function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));

//add the grid
chart1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(make_y_axis()
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat("")
  )

chart1.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("d", valueline(data1));

chart1.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line2")
  .attr("d", valueline2(data1.filter(function(d) {
    return d.date > parseDate("26-Dec-12");
  })));

// Add the X Axis
chart1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
chart1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

chart1.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + 3) + "," + y(data1[0].clinton) + ")")
  .attr("x", ".1em")
  .attr("y", "-40")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .style("fill", "red")
  .style("font-size", "15")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .text("JAN SALES");

chart1.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + 3) + "," + y(data1[0].trump) + ")")
  .attr("x", ".1em")
  .attr("y", "10")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .style("font-size", "15")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .text("XMAS");

//plus 1: animation

var curtain = chart1.append('rect')
  .attr('x', -1 * width)
  .attr('y', -1 * height - 2)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('class', 'curtain')
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(180)')
  .style('fill', '#ffffff')

/* Optionally add a guideline */
var guideline = chart1.append('line')
  .attr('stroke', '#333')
  .attr('stroke-width', 0.4)
  .attr('class', 'guide')
  .attr('x1', 1)
  .attr('y1', 1)
  .attr('x2', 1)
  .attr('y2', height)

var t = chart1.transition()
  .delay(120)
  .duration(500)
  .ease('linear')
  .each('end', function() {
    d3.select('line.guide')
      .transition()
      .style('opacity', 0)
      .remove()
  });

t.select('rect.curtain')
  .attr('width', 0);
t.select('line.guide')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ', 0)')

d3.select("#show_guideline").on("change", function(e) {
  guideline.attr('stroke-width', this.checked ? 1 : 0);
  curtain.attr("opacity", this.checked ? 0.75 : 1);
});
```

```css
    path.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #004ecc;
    stroke-width: 4px;
  }
  
  path.line2 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #cc0000;
    stroke-width: 4px;
  }
  
  path.area {
    fill: #e7e7e7;
  }
  
  .guideline {
    margin-right: 100px;
    float: right;
  }
  
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 5px;
  }
  
  .x.axis path {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .y.axis path {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .grid .tick {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 0.2px;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="florida"></div>
```

This is only one of the ways to do it. There are another approaches, such as using `line.defined` and null values.

Comment: hi, I have a question, my graph is going up in 0.5 is there a way to only up on in 1 so for example i want the graph to start at 0,1,2,3,4,5.... and so on

Comment: I have fixed my previous comment about my chart going up in 1's, another thing I want to fix is I want the line to have sharp points. when it hits the number like if '28 dec' is value '4' and '29 dec' is value '2' and '30 dec' is value '5', i want to see the line go up and down with sharp edges and not smooth. if that makes sense.

I hope it makes sense because i am struggling big time on that

Comment: Since this is another issue, please post another question. If you ask it in the comments I'm the only one reading it, but if you post another question everybody's gonna read it.

Comment: thank you for the advice, you been a good help on this. my new question is on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818388/line-chart-not-hitting-the-right-value-on-chart-and-has-a-smooth-line

Please could you check it out and help if you can