# How can I resize my d3.js script? is there a way to put this into a div tag where I can resize my bar chart smaller?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

i am unable to resize my bar chart within a script tag. Currently the bar chat is showing up massive on the page and I would like to resize the chart into a smaller size on the page.

Is there a way to resize this using CSS or JavaScript or put it into a Div? I tried to give the script tag a 'id' or 'value' but no luck.

Could someone help me resize my chart please.

this is me d3.js:

```
<script>

    data = [
        {label:"Jan Sales", value:35},
        {label:"XMAS", value:5},

    ];

    var div = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

    var axisMargin = 20,
            margin = 40,
            valueMargin = 4,
            width = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width'), 10),
            height = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('height'), 10),
            barHeight = (height-axisMargin-margin*2)* 0.2/data.length,
            barPadding = (height-axisMargin-margin*2)*0.6/data.length,
            data, bar, svg, scale, xAxis, labelWidth = 0;

    max = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; });

    svg = d3.select('body')
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);


    bar = svg.selectAll("g")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("g");

    bar.attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("cx",0)
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                return "translate(" + margin + "," + (i * (barHeight + barPadding) + barPadding) + ")";
            });

    bar.append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
            .attr("dy", ".35em") //vertical align middle
            .text(function(d){
                return d.label;
            }).each(function() {
        labelWidth = Math.ceil(Math.max(labelWidth, this.getBBox().width));
    });

    scale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, max])
            .range([0, width - margin*2 - labelWidth]);

    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(scale)
            .tickSize(-height + 2*margin + axisMargin)
            .orient("bottom");

    bar.append("rect")
            .attr("transform", "translate("+labelWidth+", 0)")
            .attr("height", barHeight)
            .attr("width", function(d){
                return scale(d.value);
            });

    bar.append("text")
            .attr("class", "value")
            .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
            .attr("dx", -valueMargin + labelWidth) //margin right
            .attr("dy", ".35em") //vertical align middle
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .text(function(d){
                return (d.value+"%");
            })
            .attr("x", function(d){
                var width = this.getBBox().width;
                return Math.max(width + valueMargin, scale(d.value));
            });

    bar
            .on("mousemove", function(d){
                div.style("left", d3.event.pageX+10+"px");
                div.style("top", d3.event.pageY-25+"px");
                div.style("display", "inline-block");
                div.html((d.label)+"<br>"+(d.value)+"%");
            });
    bar
            .on("mouseout", function(d){
                div.style("display", "none");
            });

    svg.insert("g",":first-child")
            .attr("class", "axisHorizontal")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin + labelWidth) + ","+ (height - axisMargin - margin)+")")
            .call(xAxis);

</script>
```

This is my CSS:

```
    svg {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: center;
    }

    .toolTip {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
        border: 0 none;
        border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        box-shadow: -3px 3px 15px #888888;
        color: black;
        font: 12px sans-serif;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    text {
        font: 15px sans-serif;
        color: white;
    }
    text.value {
        font-size: 100%;
        fill: white;
    }

    .axisHorizontal path{
        fill: none;
    }

    .axisHorizontal .tick line {
        stroke-width: 1;
        stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    .bar {
        fill: steelblue;
        fill-opacity: .9;
    font-size: 120%;
    }
  #search {



 position:absolute;
    top: -2%;
}
.tablebad thead tr {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.tablegood thead tr th {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: This `width = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width'), 10)` makes the SVG the same width of the window. If you want a smaller value, just set a smaller value.

Comment: I already tried that. however it ruins the whole chart, i was hoping if i can put this into a div then i can use that div to place and resize how i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `viewBox` attribute to the `svg` element. This will allow you to lock the `svg` to the exact dimensions of your graph using the `min-x`, `min-y`, `width` and `height` parameters.

Then you can resize the `svg` element and you're graph will stretch to grow bigger or smaller.

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute

Edit:
Here is your js fiddle updated to use viewBox. I've commented out the width and height attributes so that it resizes as you make the page wider or narrower.

https://jsfiddle.net/cexLbfnk/1/

Is this the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: i tried to do that but its not working, are you able to show me with my code? if you dont mind

Comment: Sure, it'll have to wait until I get home in a few hours though.

Comment: Sure, I'm happy to wait. thank you because you are helping me a lot. its been bugging me all day and if you can do this in a few hours that be amazing!!!!

Appropriate you doing this for me honestly.

Comment: There seem to be quite a few compile errors, I fixed a few here: https://jsfiddle.net/xera5zd4/. I wonder if it's happened when you copied the code from your editor? Quite a few missing spaces and stuff. If you can get the jsfiddle showing your chart properly and link the fixed version here I'll add the viewBox.

Comment: hi, i have created a new chart that i would like to have in the middle of the web page. The link is: https://jsfiddle.net/dave1231/cexLbfnk/
 As you can see when you resize the fiddle the chart does not resize according to the size of the page. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: which answer? my js fiddle?

Comment: At the bottom of my answer I added an edit with this link: https://jsfiddle.net/cexLbfnk/1/

Comment: omg thank you! saved my life. I have another question on here. do you think you could help me? its regarding a line graph that im having an issue with? if you dont mind

Comment: No problemo. Afraid I've got guests arriving soon though that I have to deal with, you'll have to post it as a separate question, good luck!

Comment: the link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797864/line-graph-using-d3-is-not-starting-from-the-date-i-want-it-to

the recent comment is mine and that what i need help with

Comment: Hi i have updated my comment on my other question the updated link is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797864/line-graph-using-d3-is-not-starting-from-the-date-i-want-it-to

if you scroll to the bottom you will see my latest comment on what i am stuck on. I hope you have a good evening and hope to see you reply soon

Comment: Hi  user3432422,

I hope you are well and had a good evening last nigh, I have posted a new question on the below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818388/line-chart-not-hitting-the-right-value-on-chart-and-has-a-smooth-line

Could you take a look at it if you can and maybe help me if you are able too!

thank you!

Comment: The viewBox attribute is specific to SVG so it won't work for canvas. That isn't to say there isn't a solution though, but I've not used the canvas renderer before, so you'll probably be better off posting it as a separate question.