# Line chart not hitting the right value on chart and has a smooth line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, nvd3.js

Below is my line graph where I am using 2 lines to show different values,

One line is blue and the other is red.

I want the line to have sharp points. and i would like the line it sit on the right vaule that i have gievn. for example if '28 dec' is value '4' and '29 dec' is value '2' and '30 dec' is value '5', Right now the values are not exactly hitting the number for example on 'Dec 25' the value is 3 but on the chart the line is going under 3 and it looks like 2.5. is this because the line is a smooth line and not a sharpe one?

I want to see the line go up and down with sharp edges and not smooth. if that makes sense. I hope it makes sense because i am struggling big time on that

the js fiddle i have created is: https://jsfiddle.net/dave1231/cexLbfnk/2/

if someone is able to show me how i would appreciate that a lot.

Thanks you in advance!

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="LineChart"></div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
  #search {
     position:absolute;
    top: -2%;
 }

 #LineChart{
  text-align:center;
}

.tablebad thead tr {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.tablegood thead tr th {
    background-color: #eee;
}


path.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #004ecc;
    stroke-width: 4px;
  }

  path.line2 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #cc0000;
    stroke-width: 4px;
  }

  path.area {
    fill: #e7e7e7;
  }

  .guideline {
    margin-right: 100px;
    float: right;
  }

  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 5px;
  }

  .x.axis path {
    display: none;
  }

  .y.axis path {
    display: none;
  }

  .grid .tick {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 0.2px;

    }
#fade p {


    text-align: center;
    animation: fadein 4s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 4s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 4s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 4s; /* Opera */
}

#fade ul,li {

    animation: fadein 4s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 4s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 4s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 4s; /* Opera */
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

This is my d3.js:

```
var margin = {
    top: 0,
    right: 90,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  padding = 1;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([10, width - 15]);

var x2 = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([10, width], .10)

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 100]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b %d"))
  .ticks(4)
  .tickPadding(2);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.XMAS);
  });

var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.JANSALES);
  });

//florida

var chart1 = d3.select("#LineChart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//needed for the grid
function make_y_axis() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
}

data1 = [{
    "date": "24-Dec-12",
    "XMAS": 2,
    "JANSALES": 0
  }, {
    "date": "25-Dec-12",
    "XMAS": 3,
    "JANSALES": 0
  },

  {
    "date": "26-Dec-12",
    "XMAS": 1,
    "JANSALES": 0
  },

  {
    "date": "27-Dec-12",
    "XMAS": 2.0,
    "JANSALES": 0
  },

  {
    "date": "28-Dec-12",
    "XMAS": 4.0,
    "JANSALES": 0
  },

  {
    "date": "29-Dec-12",
    "XMAS": 4.0,
    "JANSALES": 0
  }
  ,

  {
    "date": "29-Dec-12",
    "XMAS": 5,
    "JANSALES": 0
  },

  {
    "date": "30-Dec-12",
    "JANSALES": 3.0
  },

  {
    "date": "31-Dec-12",

    "JANSALES": 2.0
  },

  {
    "date": "01-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 3.0
  },

  {
    "date": "02-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 1.0
  },

  {
    "date": "03-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 3.0
  },

  {
    "date": "04-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 2.0
  },

  {
    "date": "05-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 2.0
  },

  {
    "date": "06-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 1.0
  },

  {
    "date": "07-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 2.0
  },

  {
    "date": "08-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 2.0
  },

  {
    "date": "09-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 3.0
  },

  {
    "date": "10-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 2.0
  },

  {
    "date": "11-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 3.0
  },

  {
    "date": "12-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 3.0
  },

  {
    "date": "13-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 2.0
  },

  {
    "date": "14-Jan-13",

    "JANSALES": 1.0
  }
];


var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#004ecc", "#cc0000"]);
//d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
data1.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.XMAS = +d.XMAS;
  d.JANSALES = +d.JANSALES;
});

// Scale the range of the data


x.domain(d3.extent(data1, function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));
y.domain([0, 10]);

x2.domain(data1.map(function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));

//add the grid
chart1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(make_y_axis()
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat("")
  )

chart1.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("d", valueline(data1));

chart1.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line2")
  .attr("d", valueline2(data1.filter(function(d) {
    return d.date > parseDate("29-Dec-12");
  })));

// Add the X Axis
chart1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
chart1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

chart1.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + 3) + "," + y(data1[0].JANSALES) + ")")
  .attr("x", ".1em")
  .attr("y", "-40")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .style("fill", "red")
  .style("font-size", "15")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .text("JAN SALES");

chart1.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + 3) + "," + y(data1[0].XMAS) + ")")
  .attr("x", ".1em")
  .attr("y", "10")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .style("font-size", "15")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .text("XMAS");

//plus 1: animation

var curtain = chart1.append('rect')
  .attr('x', -1 * width)
  .attr('y', -1 * height - 2)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('class', 'curtain')
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(180)')
  .style('fill', '#ffffff')

/* Optionally add a guideline */
var guideline = chart1.append('line')
  .attr('stroke', '#333')
  .attr('stroke-width', 0.4)
  .attr('class', 'guide')
  .attr('x1', 1)
  .attr('y1', 1)
  .attr('x2', 1)
  .attr('y2', height)

var t = chart1.transition()
  .delay(120)
  .duration(500)
  .ease('linear')
  .each('end', function() {
    d3.select('line.guide')
      .transition()
      .style('opacity', 0)
      .remove()
  });

t.select('rect.curtain')
  .attr('width', 0);
t.select('line.guide')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ', 0)')

d3.select("#show_guideline").on("change", function(e) {


});
```

Comment: isn't the removal of   `.interpolate("basis")` in both places what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `interpolate` function here:

```
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.XMAS);
    });
```

And do the same in `valueline2`. Right now you're using `basis`, which creates a [B-spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline).

In case you want to set a different interpolation, [here is a list](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Shapes.md#line_interpolate) of available options in D3 v3.x.

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7apnhbqd/

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want d3 to smooth the edges, you should remove the interpolation from the line generator.

https://jsfiddle.net/cexLbfnk/3/

```
var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis") // this line needs to go
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.JANSALES);
  });
```

Comment: Also you helped me on the bar chart being responsive  to the page. is there a way to do this for this line chart?